# Sending images via commands, in a loop?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So what I want to do is sending pictures about a game character (items, runes, etc) if the user types in the code with the character's name, (?character1) the bot sends the picture. This is pretty easy.

```
@client.command()
async def character1(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('character1.png'))

@client.command()
async def character2(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('character2.png'))

@client.command
async def character3(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('character3.png'))
```

But there are a lot of characters, and I was wondering if I could save some time with a method that looks at the command that the user sent and checks it if there is a picture with the name of the command, and then sends it. Since like in my example the commands and the names of the pictures are the same except the .png extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an argument like so:

```py
@client.command()
async def character(ctx, num):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f'character{num}.png'))
```

Which means that the command format would be, for example:
`?character 1`

---

**References:**

- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6+

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, with this code, I'm having the following error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'character1.png'

Comment: @y_os Where are the pictures? If they're in the same folder as the bot's file, then that should work, otherwise you can get their relative path, such as `file=discord.File(f'path/to/character{num}.png')`

Comment: They are in the same folder, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: I'm just curious - if you make a new folder in the same folder and place the pictures in there and then access the pictures through the folder, does the same error get thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner and I'm pretty bad so I misread the code, It's working now, I just didn't understand that I should erase the "character" from the f'character. Now it's working, thank you very much!

Comment: Ahh, no worries! Great work getting it running :) Good luck with the bot!